# cakephp 3 add unique constraint

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, validationrule

I tried the following to add a unique validation rule to my model:

```
$validator
            ->requirePresence('pseudonym', 'create',['rule' => 'isUnique'])
            ->notEmpty('pseudonym');
```

Now I don't get any errors. If I add a database-constraint I only get a database-error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Stella' for key
>   'pseudonym'

If I add:

```
$validator
        ->add('pseudonym','unique',['rule' => 'validateUnique']);
```

I get the following exception:

> Method validateUnique not found

So how does it work with cakephp 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP has a Rule class that allows you to define unique fields http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules

```
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;

// A single field.
$rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));

// A list of fields
$rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username', 'account_id']));
```

Comment: I know this is old. But I have an AdressesUsers Table and I don´t want duplicate entries for user_id and adress_id - isUnique doesn´t seem to work. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Add provider key which determines where method is defined

```
$validator
        ->add('pseudonym','unique',['rule' => 'validateUnique','provider' => 'table']);
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#adding-validation-providers